# jQuery .css not working for p and p.class

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have a jQuery function that re-sizes font-size and line-height for many elements in a page, including p and p.latest_news. **The function works as expected with all other elements, except with p.latest_news**

The font-size and line-height being applied to p.latest_news equal the p no class (i.e. `$('p').css({...` )

jQuery.1.7.1

CODE

```
    $('p.article_news').css({
            'font-size' : Math.max(11,(.9 * newFontSize)),
            'line-height' : Math.max(13,(1.1 * newFontSize))+'px'
            });
    $('p').css({
            'font-size' : Math.max(14,newFontSize),
            'line-height' : Math.max(21,(1.7 * newFontSize))+'px'
            });
```

if I only use

```
    $('p.article_news').css({
            'font-size' : Math.max(11,(.9 * newFontSize)),
            'line-height' : Math.max(13,(1.1 * newFontSize))+'px'
            });
```

p.article_news font-size and line-height change as expected

Why is this happening?
How can I affect each p, class and classless?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the article_news font size then changing it again with your second selector.

What you need is:

```
$('p.article_news').css({
        'font-size' : Math.max(11,(.9 * newFontSize)),
        'line-height' : Math.max(13,(1.1 * newFontSize))+'px'
        });
$('p:not(.article_news)').css({
        'font-size' : Math.max(14,newFontSize),
        'line-height' : Math.max(21,(1.7 * newFontSize))+'px'
        });
```

the :not() selector is basically selecting all p nodes that do not have the class .active_news.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! question to round up the knowledge... What is the syntax for cases where I have more than one p.class? (i.e. $('p:not(.one_class), p:not(.another_class)') or $('p:not(.one_class)', 'p:not(.another_class)') or COULD YOU TELL ME?

Comment: I believe comma separated values should work. :not(.classone, .classtwo) etc.
Here is a link to the api docs for :not() http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Just flip your functions. Use the function with the p selector first followed by the function with the p.article_news selector.

Your p selector function is overriding the p.article_news selector function.

Answer (score 1):

I like Mark's solution.

But if both the functions are called together you can rather flip them and make them work.

```
$('p').css({
            'font-size' : Math.max(14,newFontSize),
            'line-height' : Math.max(21,(1.7 * newFontSize))+'px'
            });
$('p.article_news').css({
            'font-size' : Math.max(11,(.9 * newFontSize)),
            'line-height' : Math.max(13,(1.1 * newFontSize))+'px'
            });
```

Might be faster than checking with `:not`

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the styles you added in `p.article_news` when you style `p` because all `p.article_news` are `p`. You can style the `p` first then the `p.article_news`, or you can use `p:not(.article_news)` instead of `p`.